# ¿Como puedo agregarle una coma a una expresión delimitadora de caracteres?

Tags: php, regex

¿Como puedo agregarle una coma a esta expresión para que también las permita?

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ]+$/i', $str);
```

Comment: ¿La esta respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 1):

Solo tenes que agregar `,` dentro de los corchetes, por ejemplo, así:

```
/^[a-zA-Z áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ,]+$/i
```

---

**Observación:**

Estas usando la bandera `i`, lo que significa que la ejecusión sera `case insensitive` (*no distingue minúsculas ni mayúsculas*), por lo  que podrías sacar las letras mayúsculas sin afectar la `RegEx`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
/^[a-z áéíóúñ,]+$/i
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/630404dabfe32fb7deea62b294285ca404949564)</kbd>